# How to match string by using regular expression which will not allow same special character at same time?

Tags: c#, regex

I m trying to matching a string which will not allow same special character at same time

my  regular expression is:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.&' '-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$")]
```

this solve my all requirement except the below two issues

this is my string : `bracks`

**acceptable** :

```
bra-cks, b-r-a-c-ks, b.r.a.c.ks,  bra cks (by the way above regular expression solved this)
```

**not acceptable**:

```
issue 1: b.. or bra..cks, b..racks, bra...cks (two or more any special character together),  
issue 2: bra    cks (two ore more white space together)
```

Comment: Your last examples have two of the *same* characters. What about `bra.-cks`? Is that OK or not OK? What about `bra,c-ks`?

Comment: ya you caught it right.. bra.-cks it is not also ok. but the above regular expression validate comma. i mean any comma will not acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks on your current regex:

- It looks like you placed the `+` quantifiers *before* the pattern you wanted to quantify, instead of *after*. For instance, `^+` doesn't make much sense, since `^` is just the start of the input, and most regex engines would not even allow that.
- The pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9.&' '-]+` doesn't distinguish between alphanumerical and other characters, while you want the rules for them to be different. Especially for the other characters you *don't* want them to repeat, so that `+` is not desired for those.
- In a character class it doesn't make sense to repeat the same character, like you have a repeat of a quote (`'`). Maybe you wanted to somehow delimit the space, but realise that those quotes are interpreted *literally*. So probably you should just remove them. Or if you intended to allow for a quote, only list it once.

Here is a correction (add the quote if you still need it):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[.& -][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

#### Follow-up

Based on a comment, I suspect you would allow a non-alphanumerical character to be surrounded by single spaces, even if that gives a sequence of more than one non-alphanumerical character. In that case use this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:[ ]|[ ]?[.&-][ ]?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

So here the space gets a different role: it can optionally occur before and after a delimiter (one of ".&-"), or it can occur on its own. The brackets around the spaces are not needed, but I used them to stress that the space is *intended* and not a typo.

Comment: Thanks, I jsut applied your soulition and it works in every situation. but when I put  '& sign' between two word it does not work. like -- swis & swon.  according to the requirement its valid. but it shows me invalid.  but thanks again..

Comment: It is rejected because ` & ` is a sequence of three non-alphanumerical characters, which I thought you didn't want to be consecutive. Are you saying a space is to be dealt with differently? What are the rules for spaces then?

Comment: @MhDip - It sounds like you're changing the requirements. You should read [ask] and then edit your question to make your requirements clear.

Comment: This would not allow strings that begin or end with a special character, which is not explicitly disallowed by the specs of the question. The OP may want to clarify this particular case.

Comment: True, @blhsing, that requirement was taken from their own regex attempt.

Comment: @MhDip, have a look at the addition to my answer. But please take note of the comments made: your question leaves much to desire. The requirements are not clearly laid out in your question, and your comment here suggests that there are more rules you have not specified.

Comment: No no no.. please don't take this in a wrong way.. i m sorry.. ":according to the requirement its valid" .. i was just giving this as statement.. it is the the requirement from my user.. not my question..

Comment: OK, but your comment *"it shows me invalid"* seems to suggest you don't understand why it is doing that, and you were not expecting that. Please realise that such a comment casts doubt on the solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to invalidate strings containing two consecutive special characters:

```
^(?!.*[.&' -]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.&' -]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7j14bu/1

Answer (score 1):

**The goal**

From what i can tell by your description and pattern, you are trying to match text, which start and end with alphanumeric (due to `^+[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]$` inyour original pattern), and inside, you just don't want to have any two consecuive (adjacent) special characters, which, again, guessing from the regex, are `.` `&`   `'` `-`

**What was wrong**

`^+` - i think here you wanted to assure that match starts at the beginning of the line/string, so you don't need `+` here

`[a-zA-Z0-9.&' '-]` - in this character class you doubled `'` which is totally unnecessary

**Solution**

Please try pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?![.& '-]{2,})[a-zA-Z0-9.& '-])*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Pattern explanation

`^` - anchor, match the beginning of the string

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` - character class, match one of the characters inside `[]`

`(?:...)` - non capturing group

`(?!...)` - negative lookahead

`[.& '-]{2,}` - match 2 or more of characters inside character class

`[a-zA-Z0-9.& '-]` - character class, match one of the characters inside `[]`

`*` - match zero or more text matching preceeding pattern

`$` - anchor, match the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UwTPqh/1)